# increase ulimit for # of file descriptors

Tags: file-descriptor, ulimit

As `normaluser`:

```
$ ulimit -n 4096
-bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted
```

As root it works as desired - but then it won't affect `normaluser`.

How to get out of this catch 22?  I'll need this to be persistent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look at /etc/security/limits.conf

Comment: That felt kludgy but I think it did exactly what I wanted.  I'll leave this question open a bit in case there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

To change file descriptor limit as normal user before running any applicaiton.

I use this small utility [fdlimit](https://github.com/syrajendra/fdlimit) which will increase file descriptor limit using "[setrlimit()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit)" system call before executing any program.

I use it like this

```
$ sudo ./fdlimit <fdlimit> <program_to_run>
```